# One hot encoding increases sizes of target data

Tags: machine-learning, keras

i have multiclass  data, label or y columns contains following  data :

```
print(y.unique())
```

[5 6 7 4 8 3 9]
in this case number of class is equal to 7(when modelling of deep learning), but when i do one hot encoding like this :

```
import keras
from keras.utils import np_utils
y_train =np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test =np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
```

dimension increased to 10

print(y_train.shape) : (4547, 10)

maybe because  we have numbers up to 9  and (0,1,2) is also included(in fact it is not represented in original data), how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that the maximum value is 9, and `to_categorical` assumes a starting class of 0. So then you get 10 classes (i.e., 0 through 9).

Comment: is it ok to use such approach

Comment: It depends on your problem. Do you ever have a case where a label is 0? or 1? Or are the labels `5 6 7 4 8 3 9` the only ones you ever see?

Comment: yes  only 5,6,7,4,8,39 are labels  in the  dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical` requires the inputs to be "integers from 0 to `num_classes`" (see the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical)). You have a set of labels `{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`. That is a total of seven labels, which start at the value 3. To transform this to a set of labels in [0, 7), one can subtract 3 from each label.

```py
y_ints = y - 3
```

The result can be passed to `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical`.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

y = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
y_ints = y - 3  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_ints)
```

and output is

```py
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

---

Another option is to use scikit-learn's extensive preprocessing methods, in particular [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

y = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)  # reshape to (n_samples, n_labels).
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, dtype="float32")
encoder.fit_transform(y)
```

The output is

```py
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```